# Suppose a random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 =1$, does the joint density of the random vector exist?

Tags: probability

Suppose a random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 =1$, does the joint density of the random vector exist? It appears to be that at first sight it doesn't since it is equivalent to constructing a hyperplane and hence volume wouldn't exist, but are there trivial examples where this might not hold?

Comment: The reasoning is correct: $P(X\in S)=1$ where $S$ is the unit sphere hence $S$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, which implies that the distribution of $X$ has no PDF.

Comment: In that case the support of $X$ is a subset of the sphere, it's not a hyperplane.

Comment: The PDF exists on the unit $n-1$ sphere, but in $\Bbb R^n$ it only exists in the form of something similar to the Dirac $\delta$.

Comment: @Arthur And since Dirac measures have no PDF, this means there is no PDF in $\mathbb R^n$, in any "form" whatsoever.

Comment: @Did There is if you ask a physicist. Also, the _distribution_ exists on $\Bbb R^n$, no matter how strict you are. But no, there isn't really a PDF.

Comment: @Arthur Even a physicist (just joking) would recognize there is a PDF on the sphere, not on the space $\mathbb R^n$, that is, $$P(X\in B)=\int_{S_{n-1}}\mathbf 1_B(x)f(x)d\sigma_{n-1}(x)$$ for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$, which is quite different from $$P(X\in B)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\mathbf 1_B(x)f(x)dx$$ so no, they would not invoke a PDF on $\mathbb R^n$.